# Raw socket sendto() failure in OS X

Tags: sockets, macos

When I open a raw socket is OS X, construct my own udp packet (headers and data), and call sendto(), I get the error "Invalid Argument".  Here is a sample program "rawudp.c" from the web site http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html that demonstrates this problem.  The program (after adding string and stdlib #includes) runs under Fedora 10 but fails with "Invalid Argument" under OS X.  Can anyone suggest why this fails in OS X?  I have looked and looked and looked at the sendto() call, but all the parameters look good.  I'm running the code as root, etc.  Is there perhaps a kernel setting that prevents even uid 0 executables from sending packets through raw sockets in OS X Snow Leopard?  Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question, but it's really going to get better answers from programmers. For that reason, I'm voting to migrate it to http://www.stackoverflow.com. Once a few more people vote, it will happen automatically, so you don't need to recreate it there.

Answer (score 7):

I may have solved the mystery.
I too crafted a raw socket example, which runs fine on Linux, but got "Invalid Argument" error on OS X 10.6.
I encountered this page "[FreeBSD socket bugs and peculiarities](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ebraghava/notes/freebsd-sockets.txt)" while googling for an answer. And it says:

> Writing to RAW sockets
>
> ---
>
> **- ip_len and ip_off must be in host byte order**

So I replace

```
ip.ip_len = htons(len);
```

with

```
ip.ip_len = len;
```

on OS X. And it works, however strange it is.

Comment: The behavior actually is documented in Steven's "Unix Network Programming" Volume I  Chapter 25 "Raw socket" 2nd edition.

Answer (score 3):

user37278, I ran the same program on my Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) and get the same error message. I found the problem is that the custom IP header structure is incoherent with the IP header format. (Might have something to do difference in machines.. I'm not sure).

What I did was I removed his custom IP header structure and used the IP header struct included with Mac OS X. The header information is defined in `<netinet/ip.h>` and the struct is `struct ip`. I also found another struct called `struct iphdr` and I'm not sure the difference.

The headers I included are `<netinet/ip.h> <netinet/udp.h> <netinet/in.h> <arpa/inet.h>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD takes another approach. It *never* passes TCP or UDP packets to raw
sockets. Such packets need to be read directly at the datalink layer by using
libraries like libpcap or the bpf API. It also *never* passes any fragmented 
datagram. Each datagram has to be completeley reassembled before it is passed
to a raw socket.

this might go for OSX as well

Source:
http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw